# Export data to Google Sheet using PHP

Tags: python, php, google-drive-api

With `localhost` it works fine. I connected this python script with PHP and it does his job.

However, when I use this python script in Hosted Web it does not work (even if the hoster provide Python support).

**- What is wrong with my code?**

**- Python not working on Hosting? Or do any of you have similar code in php ?**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
 
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_key.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet = client.open('CSV-to-Google-Sheet')

with open('Data.csv', 'r') as file_obj:
        content = file_obj.read()
        client.import_csv('gsheets_id', data=content)
```

Comment: "_python not working on Hosting_" Does your hoster provide Python support? We don't know

Comment: @brombeer yes it does support